# Переводы строки в массиве, полученном .collect при обработке дат для календаря Tadayoshi Funaba

Tags: ruby

Изучаю программу-календарь Tadayoshi Funaba (cal.rb)

Сначала создается массив обозначений дней недели для работы календаря с отсчетом от текущей даты:

```
 require 'date'
 fi = Date.new(1, 1, 1)
 ve  = (fi..fi +  6).collect{|cu|
  %w(Вс Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб)[cu.wday]
 }
 => ["Сб", "Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт"]
```

Вот тут массив ведет себя так, как привычно любому новичку. Потом к этому массиву прибавляются номера дней в месяце, чтобы таким образом получить массив-заготовку, необходимую для преобразования его в вывод календаря данного месяца:

```
ve += (fi..fi + 41).collect{|cu|
 if cu.mon == 1 then cu.send(:mday) end.to_s
}
=>
["Сб",
 "Вс",
 "Пн",
 "Вт",
 "Ср",
 "Чт",
 "Пт",
 "1",
 "2",
 "3",
 "4",
 "5",
 "6",
 "7",
 "8",
 "9",
 "10",
 "11",
 "12",
 "13",
 "14",
 "15",
 "16",
 "17",
 "18",
 "19",
 "20",
 "21",
 "22",
 "23",
 "24",
 "25",
 "26",
 "27",
 "28",
 "29",
 "30",
 "31",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 "",
 ""]
```

И тут мы получаем кучу переводов строки, как будто это мультистрока, а не массив... откуда они взялись, и как это работает?

Далее эти переводы сохраняются при выделении подмассивов:

```
(0..ve.size / 7 - 1).collect{|i| ve[i * 7, 7]}
=>
[["Сб", "Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт"],
 [" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7"],
 [" 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"],
 ["15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"],
 ["22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"],
 ["29", "30", "31", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "],
 ["  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "]]
```

Что происходит с массивами решительно не понимаю, может это какой-то не объясненный подробно эффект методов модуля date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это всего лишь способ отображения в консоли, в массиве по-прежнему хранятся те же самые элементы. Попробуйте в консоли выполнить

```
pry(main)> (0..30).to_a
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
pry(main)> (0..100).to_a
=> [0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 ....
 96,
 97,
 98,
 99,
 100]
pry(main)> print (0..100).to_a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]=> nil
```